# Splitting QString on spaces and keeping the space in QList - best or 'canonical' way

Tags: c++, qt, split, qstring, qlist

As in the title, I would like to ask what is the best way to split a QString on spaces and - where relevant - keep the spaces as parts of the resulting QList elements. I'm interested in the most efficient method of doing this, considering modern C++ and Qt >= 6.0 paradigms.

For the purpose of this question I will replace normal spaces with '_' - I hope it makes the problem easier to understand.

Imagine the following code:

```
QString myString = "This_is_an_exemplary_text";
for (auto word : myString.split('_')) {
   qDebug() << word;
}
```

The output of the code would be:

> "This"
> "is"
> "an"
> "exemplary"
> "text"

Information about the spaces was lost in the splitting process. Is there a smart way to preserve it, and have the following output:

> "This_"
> "is_"
> "an_"
> "exemplary_"
> "text"

Any suggestion would be welcomed.

Comment: One possibility: use `splitRef` instead, this gives you a vector of `QStringRef` references into the original string. You can walk that list and see if the separator immediately follows the given reference.

Comment: Not sure if `QRegularExpression` supports look-behind assertions. If it does, try splitting on `QRegularExpression("(?<= )"` ; this basically says "a point in the string preceded by a space".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - thank you, this works like a charm. If you don't mind - write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `myString.split(QRegularExpression("(?<= )")` The regular expression says "an empty substring preceded by a space", using the positive look-behind syntax.